# How to save an image dynamically

Tags: objective-c

I am using photo library in my app. And after selecting image from photo library or camera i want to save that image into my Documents folder. So here i want to give name to that image while saving is it possible to set name to the selected image? If means please let me know. I am trying that only if possible i will post that.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it.. I'm copying and pasting my code so there's some additional functionality.

```
// image is a UIImage
// inputText is the user selected imagename
// date is a string I inserting to make pictures a unique identifier (i.e. no duplicate names)
NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@.jpg", inputText,date];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], imageFilename];

if([imageData1 writeToFile:path atomically:YES]){
    NSLog(@"Write to Document folder success filename = %@",path);
}
```

Comment: I saw your below comment and I do allow for image naming.. I use display a uialertview after taking the picture.  the "inputText" variable is the userinput captured in the alertview

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *photoImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSString *savedDoc = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/myImageName.png"];
BOOL status = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedDoc];

if(status){

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedDoc error:nil];

}
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoImage) writeToFile:savedDoc atomically:YES];
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You can set any desired name when saving to document directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i want to give name to that particular image dynamically and want to add multiple images. From the above code we can save but if already exists it will replace na...

Comment: yes of course.But if you don't what that then don't replace it.When "status" is YES then simply change the name by appending any Integer value in the name string which will always increase when saving the image.Declare this integer in header file and increase it when saving image.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer counterNo and initialize it to 0. And increase its value to change name dynamically.

```
UIImage *photoImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

counterNo++;

NSString *aaa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/myImage-%d.png" , counterNo];
NSString *savedDoc = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:aaa];
BOOL status = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedDoc];

if(status){

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedDoc error:nil];

}
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoImage) writeToFile:savedDoc atomically:YES];
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```